# I can't get celery working properly (aws elasticbeanstalk)

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm moving a django app to python3/django 1.10. Part of the process include also a new deployment and we use AWS EBS.

The celery tasks were ok before the migration, but now I can't get the tasks works properly.

The packages:

```
...
celery==3.1.23
Django==1.10.6
django-celery==3.2.1
...
```

Python:

```
Python 3.4.3
```

On the supervisor configuration I added a configuration to run celery:

```
[program:celeryd-workers]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true    
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
environment=PYTHONPATH="/opt/python/current/app/:",PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin/:%(ENV_PATH)s",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.qa"

[program:celeryd-beat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery beat -A app --app=app.celery_app:app --loglevel=DEBUG --workdir=/tmp --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat.pid -s /tmp/celerybeat-schedule.db
directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true

stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
environment=PYTHONPATH="/opt/python/current/app/:",PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin/:%(ENV_PATH)s",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.qa"
```

my celery_app.py is pretty simple:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

app = Celery()

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

The configuration

On the EC2 instance the settings for celery:

```
BROKER_URL = 'the aws elastic cache redis url'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'visibility_timeout': 600,
}

BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack']

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'exchange': 'default',
        'exchange_type': 'topic',
        'binding_key': 'tasks.#'
    }
}

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

From the instance I checked the configuration (from django.conf import settings), and I checked if the instance can connect to redis using `redis-cli`.

## What doesn't work?

Basically if I run a task, even the simplest one like the `add(x,y)` as in the celery documentation, I don't get the tasks in the `./manage.py celery events`, I left the events open for a couple of hours and I tried to run the tasks from the app, but nothing happens and seems stuck.

```
 No task selected                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│  Workers online: celery@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx                                                                                                                                                            │
│  Info: events: 2187 tasks:0 workers:1/1
│  Keys: j:down k:up i:info t:traceback r:result c:revoke ^c: quit
```

What is weird is if I run this task as in the docs in my app:

```
In [1]: from app.core.tasks import add

In [2]: result = add.delay(2,2)

In [3]: result.get()
Out[3]: 4
```

The result appears, but I can't see any tasks in the events and if I check the `celery inspect statistics`

```
...
       "pool": {
            "max-concurrency": 4,
            "max-tasks-per-child": "N/A",
            "processes": [
                11363,
                11364,
                11365,
                11366
            ],
            "put-guarded-by-semaphore": false,
            "timeouts": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "writes": {
                "all": "",
                "avg": "0.00%",
                "inqueues": {
                    "active": 0,
                    "total": 4
                },
                "raw": "",
                "total": 0
            }
        },
....
```

Simply seems nothing works.

Of course the process are runnings:

```
[ec2-user@xxx]$ ps aux | grep "celery"
nobody   11350  0.0  3.7 251484 77408 ?        S    08:11   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery beat -A app --app=app.celery_app:app --loglevel=DEBUG --workdir=/tmp --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat.pid -s /tmp/celerybeat-schedule.db
nobody   11351  0.1  3.8 247804 79848 ?        S    08:11   0:07 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
nobody   11363  0.0  3.4 243876 70956 ?        S    08:11   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
nobody   11364  0.0  3.4 243876 71024 ?        S    08:11   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
nobody   11365  0.0  3.4 243876 71024 ?        S    08:11   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
nobody   11366  0.0  3.4 243876 71024 ?        S    08:11   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A app --app=app.celery_app:app -l DEBUG -c 4
```

And the logs:

```
[ec2-user@xxxx log]$ tail  /var/log/celery-worker.log
[2017-03-14 20:34:45,126: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:34:50,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:34:55,125: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:00,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:05,125: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:10,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:15,125: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:20,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:25,125: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-03-14 20:35:30,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
```

And the celery beat:

```
[ec2-user@xxxx log]$ tail  /var/log/celery-beat.log
>>>> Testing: False
celery beat v3.1.23 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://qa-redis.xxxx:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> /tmp/celerybeat-schedule.db
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: This does not sound like an elastic beanstalk deployment as unless you are using docker, I don't understand how you can be running both the server and worker on the same deployment. Move to using docker if you really want to do this.

Comment: did you find out what's wrong? I'm migrating python2 to python3 as well and have the same issue getting the celery running.

Comment: @awwester celery or celerybeat?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings file has
`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`
which basically means it will skip the queue and run the tasks locally. Hence you get the result without seeing any events.
Have a look at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager

I'd try removing that setting and work from there.